# how to make an activity diagram in uml to support multiple activities without if/else

Tags: uml

I need to clarify my concept.
I am making activity diagrams for different activities. for an activity titled as:
'View Profile'.... i need to make its dgm...
In 'view profile' a user can:

```
1- view his/her monthly bills
2- View demographics details
3- Edit his/her details
```

and foreach 1,2,3 there would be different steps to be followed

My question is:
how should i make an activity dgm for such a situation... here is what I am tryong to communicate.. help me how to correct it or what sort of symbol should be used in between to serve the correct purpose as its upto user whether he wants to explore all 1,2,3 or only 1 or only 2 etc

[image: starting diagram]

Comment: can someone plz help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only 1 option can occur at a time: a decision point (diamond shape) would be the most appropriate (annotated "user chooses option" or similar).  The decision point would have 3 paths leading to the 3 possible options.

For clarity the paths should have arrows indicating direction.

To show that the user can perform another option after completing an initially chosen one, you could have another decision point that each of the 3 steps link to. That decision point could be named "User chooses to continue further steps?" or similar, with the "Yes" path leading back to the first decision point, and the "No" path leading to a final node.

Comment: Sorry, just saw Red Beard's answer which is the same as what I have described.. (I agree with that answer basically and suggest that as the correct one)

Comment: but each of these actions have their own steps like for edit details etc.. there are a number of steps so it wont look right if i do it the way u r sayng... can u plz chck this link: http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=cGoXEC3dMoZ5IM:&imgrefurl=http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/sample-activity-diagrams-example-25620&docid=VhUARmaKdrNHaM&imgurl=http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2605993056_f35c4df7d5_o.jpg&w=500&h=467&ei=B93WUdKfMsXEPKuvgLAN&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:9,s:0,i:111&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=190&tbnw=203&start=0&ndsp=20&tx=105&ty=74

Comment: I think that any number of steps could be added to the flow (or sub-diagram as per Red Beard's suggestion)... I was more suggesting that at the end of the set of steps for each option, you include loop back to the first decision point to show the user has the option to repeat or choose again..

Answer (score 3):

In fact I would create an activity diagram describing view profiling which would contains three CallActivities calling respectively three activities named "View details", "Edit details", and  "View bills".

Now for linking these three CallActivities inside the ViewProfile Activity I would use decision/merge nodes (depending if the threes sub activities can not be performed in parallel).

Decision node corresponding to a if/else statement but if I well understood your issue you need that **plus** the fact that after having performed one of these subactivities you should be able to performe one of them and this is modeled by a flow coming back to these subactivities

Hoping it is clear and it helps

Please take a look at my attachment.
[image]

Comment: Sir what i want is that its upto user which option he/she wants to explore ... more of that these activities are basically a part of drop down menu of 'View Profile'.. so whichever option the user will click.. he/she will be able to explore that... so its all depend on user click.... and desicion nodes i think cannot serve the purpose here... plz help me out

Comment: plz chck this link also.. they have done somewhat what I am asking but m not sure whether its a right way to do that or not... http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=cGoXEC3dMoZ5IM:&imgrefurl=http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/sample-activity-diagrams-example-25620&docid=VhUARmaKdrNHaM&imgurl=http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2605993056_f35c4df7d5_o.jpg&w=500&h=467&ei=B93WUdKfMsXEPKuvgLAN&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:9,s:0,i:111&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=190&tbnw=203&start=0&ndsp=20&tx=105&ty=74

Comment: I think decision nodes are the correct way of doing this here.. the decision is based on user selection.  The fork / join symbols in the link you provided I think are more intended to show concurrent actions.. but in this case the user can only follow one path at a time